# MYSQL - Impossible to create an external key

Tags: mysql

I am a self taught CS and I am really novice at mySQL. I created a table called "`jobs`". I would like to create a new table `keywords` with 3 columns:

- `keyword_id` as a primary key
- `job_id` as a foreign key from the `jobs` table
- `keyword`, text

This is the query I wrote:

```
   CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY(`keyword_id`),
  `keyword` text NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES jobs(job_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I got this error message:

```
Key column 'job_id' doesn't exist in table
```

The current jobs table code is the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
      `title` text NOT NULL,
      `type` text NOT NULL,
      `location` text NOT NULL,
      `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `description` text NOT NULL,
      `date` date NOT NULL,
      `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You need to create the column in the table keywords and add the foreign key constraint into it. Saying foreign key doesn’t create the column

Comment: Thank you, I already created it, I just have to add the constraint then

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a column in the `keywords` table to hold the foreign key.

Like this

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
      `title` text NOT NULL,
      `type` text NOT NULL,
      `location` text NOT NULL,
      `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `description` text NOT NULL,
      `date` date NOT NULL,
      `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
    `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `keyword` text NOT NULL,
    `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,              #<- new column
    PRIMARY KEY(`keyword_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES jobs(job_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```